# Unable to add SVG code

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-directives

I want to add icons with SVG code but when I add SVG to vuejs code it shows me an XML header tag along with icons e.g.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: I have hide it by changing font-size: 0 to its parent tag. I know its wrong. Please see this link http://d1brg6zcfjtxzw.cloudfront.net/#/bus ... The logo is in svg, I have set H1 tag font-size to 0px.